# What do these symbols $C^1_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ mean?

Tags: real-analysis, notation, function-spaces

The symbols $C^1_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ appear in this context, but I don't know the meaning of them.

Let $f$ be integrable on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $g\in C^1_0(\mathbb{R}^n).$ Then, prove that $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(y)g(x-y)  dy\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n).$

What do $C^1_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ mean ?

Comment: It often refers to $C^1$ functions with compact support. A function has compact support in $\mathbb{R}^n$ if $\overline{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid f(x) \neq 0 \}}$ is compact.

Comment: Or functions that vanish at infinity, the compact support can be denoted with a subscript "c". Although here you're right it seems to me it's the compact support one :)

Comment: And $C^1$ means functions whose first derivative is continuous.